# String segmentation with html tags in python

Tags: python, segments

I am trying to break a string into smaller segments using Python. 
The various cases can be:
str1 = "Hello world. This is an ideal example string."
Result: 
Hello world.
This is an ideal example string.

str2 = "`<H1>`Hello world.`</H1><P>`This is an HTML example string.`<P>`"
Result:
`<H1>`Hello world.`</H1>`
`<P>`This is an HTML example string.`<P>`

str3 = "1. Hello World. 2. This is a string."
Result:
1. Hello World.
2. This is a string.

Here is my code. But I cannot seem to achieve the 2nd case:

```
import re

string = """<h1>This is a string.</h1><a href="www.abc.com"> This is another part. <P/>"""

segment_regex = re.compile(r"""
    (
        \r\n|
        \\r\\n|
        \n|
        \\n|
        \r|
        \\r|
        \t|
        \\t|
        (?:
            (?<=[^\d][\.|\!|\?])
            \s+
            (?=[A-Z0-9])
        )|
        (?:
            (?<=[\.|\!|\?])\s*(?=<.*?>)
        )
    )
    """, re.VERBOSE)
seg = segment_regex.split(string)
segments = seg[::2]
separator = seg[1::2]

print("Segments are ---->>")
for s in segments:
    print (s)

print("Separators are ---->>")
for p in separator:
    print (p)
```

Comment: Are you trying to [parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/353278)?

Comment: The thing is that the source to parse can be anything - HTML or normal text. That's why I need to consider all cases.

Comment: your criteria for splitting the string seems vague to me...

Answer (score 1):

The regex may be trying to do too many things at once. A simpler and more manageable way would be to first detect the string type html, ideal, list first and then invoke appropriate processors for each. Something like :-

```
import re

string = """<h1>This is a string.</h1><a href="www.abc.com"> This is another part. <P/>"""
if re.search('<.*?>', string):
    split_html(string)
elif re.search('\\d\\.', string):
    split_list(string)
else:
    split_ideal(string)
```

Also while this may work for the cases mentioned a generic "splitter" will be far more complex and I don't claim that this approach will work for all.